# Chef shell-init on windows messing up git bash?

Tags: ruby, git, bash, chef-infra, chefdk

I've installed ChefDK on my machine (windows 7). I needed to use the embedded ruby as my system ruby, so I came across this command:

```
echo 'eval "$(chef shell-init bash)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

I ran this. It seems to have updated my system ruby to ChefDK's ruby. But now, Git bash isn't working. Any command I run I get the response: 
bash: git: command not found

Is there some change I need to make in my environment variables to fix this?

Comment: Please post the contents of your `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Did you source the `~/.bash_profile` after `echo` command?

Comment: Having the same problem.  The 'chef shell-init bash' rewrites the git-bash shell's PATH into a windows c:\ format and not a more unix/bashlike /c/

Answer (score 1):

I found this Chef Blog Posting, [The ChefDK on Windows Survival Guide](https://blog.chef.io/2014/11/04/the-chefdk-on-windows-survival-guide/)

The post clearly states,

> NOTE: The only Windows shell officially supported and recommended by Chef is Powershell. Use Bash at your own risk

As a mitigation, there is a provided solution,

Set the following in your bash profile: ( Updated for more recent ChefDK )

> RUBY_VERSION="2.3.0" export
>   PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/AppData/Local/chefdk/gem/ruby/${RUBY_VERSION}/bin:/c/opscode/chefdk/embedded/bin"
>   export
>   GEM_ROOT="/c/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/${RUBY_VERSION}"
>   export
>   GEM_HOME="${HOME}/AppData/Local/chefdk/gem/ruby/${RUBY_VERSION}"
>   export
>   GEM_PATH="/c/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/${RUBY_VERSION}"